# How to Extract Date/Time from a sentence string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string coming from the db that contains:

'Package Sent on Date/Time: 1/7/2021 7:30:00 PM Sent By: Truck'

I need to extract the datetime from the above string and format it to local time and reinsert it into the string.

I have tried looking at regex but I haven't found a solution that meets these requirements.

I thank you guys in advance. Javascript or Jquery are all options I'm open to.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const string = 'Package Sent on Date/Time: 1/7/2021 7:30:00 PM Sent By: Truck';
const res = string.match(/\d{1,2}\D\d{1,2}\D(\d{4}|\d{2})/g);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using simple regex pattern to find the date string, create a date from it, and then use the same regex to replace the old date with the new date as seen below.

I'll leave formatting the date as "*a local date*" up to you.

```js
const regex = /(: )(.*M)/;
const str = 'Package Sent on Date/Time: 1/7/2021 7:30:00 PM Sent By: Truck';
const dateFromStr = new Date(regex.exec(str)[2]);
const newStr = str.replace(regex.exec(str)[2], dateFromStr);
console.log(str);
console.log(newStr);
```